# Keras backend function seems to be working incorrectly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am trying to implement a custom loss function in Keras.

To start it off, I wanted to be sure the previous loss function can be called from my custom function. And this is where the weird stuff begins:

```
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

works as expected.

Now the implementation of "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" in keras.losses is as follows:

```
def sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
```

I concluded that passing `K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy` directly should also work. However, it throws `expected activation_6 to have shape (4,) but got array with shape (1,)`.

Also, defining a custom loss function like this:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
```

does not work. During training is reduces the loss (which seems correct) but the accuracy does not improve (but it does, when using the non-custom loss function)

I am not sure what is happening, neither do I know how to debug it properly. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what is your new code for compiling the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested what you are saying on my code and yes, you are right. I was initially getting the same error as you were getting, but once I changed the metrics parameter from `accuracy` to `sparse_categorical_accuracy`, I started getting higher accuracy.

Here, one important thing to note is when we tell keras to use `accuracy` as `metrics`, keras uses the default accuracy which is `categorical_accuracy`. So, if we want to implement our own custom loss function, then we have to set `metrics` parameter accordingly.

Read about available metrics function in keras from [here](https://keras.io/metrics/).

**Case 1:**

```
def sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

output:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_71 to have
>   shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)

**Case 2:**

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

output:

```
Epoch 1/2
60000/60000 [==============================] - 2s 38us/step - loss: 0.4714 - acc: 0.8668
Epoch 2/2
60000/60000 [==============================] - 1s 22us/step - loss: 0.2227 - acc: 0.9362
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 94us/step
```

**Case 3:**

```
def custom_sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',             
              loss=custom_sparse_categorical_crossentropy, 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

output:

```
Epoch 1/2
60000/60000 [==============================] - 2s 41us/step - loss: 0.4558 - acc: 0.1042
Epoch 2/2
60000/60000 [==============================] - 1s 22us/step - loss: 0.2164 - acc: 0.0997
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 89us/step
```

**Case 4:**

```
def custom_sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=custom_sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
              metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
```

output:

```
Epoch 1/2
60000/60000 [==============================] - 2s 40us/step - loss: 0.4736 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8673
Epoch 2/2
60000/60000 [==============================] - 1s 23us/step - loss: 0.2222 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9372
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 85us/step
```

**Full Code:**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K


mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([

tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.10),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

def custom_sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

#def sparse_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
#    # reshape in case it's in shape (num_samples, 1) instead of (num_samples,)
#    if K.ndim(y_true) == K.ndim(y_pred):
#        y_true = K.squeeze(y_true, -1)
#    # convert dense predictions to labels
#    y_pred_labels = K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
#    y_pred_labels = K.cast(y_pred_labels, K.floatx())
#    return K.cast(K.equal(y_true, y_pred_labels), K.floatx())

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=custom_sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
         metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2, batch_size=200)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Check out the implementation of `sparse_categorical_accuracy` from [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/f06524c44e5f6926968cb2bb3ddd1e523f5474c5/keras/metrics.py#L36) and `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` from [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/f06524c44e5f6926968cb2bb3ddd1e523f5474c5/keras/losses.py#L72).

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that when you use the `accuracy` metric, Kera actually selects a different accuracy implementation depending on the loss, as how the accuracy is computed depends on the labels and the predictions of the model:

- for `categorical_crossentropy` it uses `categorical_accuracy` as accuracy metric.
- for `binary_crossentropy` it uses `binary_accuracy` as accuracy metric.
- for `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` it uses `sparse_categorical_accuracy` as accuracy metric.

Keras can only do this if you use the predefined losses, as it can't guess otherwise. For your custom loss you can directly use one of the three accuracy implementations directly, like `metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy']`.